# Printing lists recursively in Python without mutating a list

Tags: python, recursion

For a homework question I want to print items from a list incrementing each item by one. I want to do this using recursion (ideally without mutating a list).

*NB: I understand that recursion is not a standard solution in Python or any other language (I don't intend to use it in any real world Python implementations) but this is part the recursion section of a CS course.*

I think this problem could be solved far more simply and in a more Pythonic way by using a simple `for` loop (I haven't learnt list comprehensions yet):

```
def iter_increment(p):
    for n in p:
        print n + 1

print iter_increment([1,2,3,4])
```

To solve this recursively I've created a copy of the list:

```
def rec_increment(p):
    if len(p) == 0:
        return
    else:
        r = list(p)
        print r.pop(0) + 1
        return rec_increment(r)

print rec_increment([1,2,3,4])
```

My question is, can the code be simplified or improved by not mutating the copy of the list while still using recursion?

Comment: `I know that recursion is not Pythonic` I wouldn't say that. (While recursion wouldn't be the standard solution here, that would be equally true in most other languages as well).

Comment: I wish there was a handbook of all the things that are not pythonic...it seems to grow all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def rec_increment(p):
    if len(p) == 0:
        return ""                    #If you return an empty string, you don't get the "None" printing at the end.
    else:
        #r = list(p)                 This is not necessary now.
        print p[0]+1                 #r.pop(0) + 1   Rather than pop, just index.
        return rec_increment(p[1:])  # Only recurse on the 2nd-nth part of the list

print rec_increment([1,2,3,4])       # Note that you don't need to both "print" in the function *and* print the result of the function - you can pick which you want to do.
```

Comment: This could be improved using indexes instead of slicing(`def rec_increment(p, start=0):` etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu True, but I think I'll leave it like this, since it more closely matches the strategy the OP was using, and the OP wasn't asking for optimization in general.

Comment: the return and print part is not really necessary, is it ?

Comment: @njzk2 It's not - I left a note about it in a code comment.  I usually try not to make too many additional changes to the OP's code so it's easier for them to understand what the fix to their stated problem is.

Comment: It’s still rather odd to have the function always return an empty string at the end of the recursion, just to make the function “printable” while it is printing the individual results itself.

Comment: @Brionius Thanks this is what I was looking for and take the point about using 'print' twice

Comment: @Bakuriu the optimization info is useful

Comment: and it looks like @poke has published an answer using indexes

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to create a new list with every recursion step, you could just recursively iterate over the indexes. For example like this:

```
def rec_increment(l, i = None):
    if i is None:
        i = len(l) - 1
    if i >= 0:
        rec_increment(l, i - 1)
        print(l[i] + 1)
```

The `i is None` check is to be able to initialize it without the second parameter.

```
>>> rec_increment([1,2,3,4])
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I'd change `i == None` to `i is None` and ... *why* are you doing recursion backwards?!? it would be easier to start at `i=0` and stop recursion when `i == len(l)`. You even avoid checking for `None`.

Comment: Indices are the way to go, but it can be a lot simpler, see my answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu Good point, changed that. Well, why shouldn’t I do it backwards? It works both ways, and I think it’s easier to check `< 0` than to query the list’s length every time.

Comment: Lists "know" their length, so even with long lists there's no performance penalty to doing it either way.

Comment: @alexis You’re technically still calling a function every time; not that it matters. Point remains, why shouldn’t I do it backwards?

Comment: I've no special problem with doing it backwards-- if it fits the problem, go for it. In this case, though, I think it's harder to read and debug (for the human reader) than some of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to implement a loop as a recursive call. Here it is, short and sweet:

```
def rtraverse(seq, i=0):
    if i < len(seq):
        print seq[i] + 1
        rtraverse(seq, i+1)

rtraverse([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The recursion ends by itself as soon as `i` exceeds the length of the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(lst, i = None):
    if i is None:
        i = 0
    if i-1 == len(lst)-1:
        return ''
    print lst[i]
    i += 1
    fun(lst, i)


fun([1,3,4,5])
```

Comment: Maybe a little bit of explanation what is going in this code? What is different compared with the other answers? Is this better? More efficient?

Answer (score 0):

[see discussions on udacity](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/stgs-recursion-collection-1st-draft/63871)

```
#'Return a list of numbers with each of its elements increased by 1.'
# This is a small jump in difficulty from the previous problem,
# so here's a hint: You don't need to mutate a list.

def rtraverse(seq, i=0):
    if i == len(seq)-1:
        return [seq[i]+1]
    return [seq[i]+1] + rtraverse(seq,i+1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok here is an attempt at recursion, I did not know the formal definition of what you meant by it at first :

```
>>> def inc(list, i=0):
...    if i < len(list):
...        list[i] += 1
...        i += 1
...        inc(list,i)
... 
>>> inc(list)
>>> list
[3, 12]
>>> inc(list)
>>> list
[4, 13]
```

Comment: That's a `SyntaxError`, using bad identifier names(`list`) and I don't see any recursion. Plus the OP explicitly stated that he cannot use list-comprehensions(which, I believe, includes gen-exps too).

Comment: 1. That's not valid python syntax. 2. He wants to use recursion. 3. This is a generator expression, not a list comprehension, so it won't return a list. 4. He hasn't learned about list comprehensions

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm new to python so I'm not to familiar with the terms "list-comprehensions". @ Haidro I did not know what he meant by "recursions", I though he just meant looping, I knew it was a generator though.

Comment: Here is my attempt at recursions.